# Булева переменная isGrounded в Character Controller

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я знаю, что в Character Controller есть булева переменная isGrounded, которая определяет, стоит ли персонаж на каком-либо объекте. Так вот, можно ли как-то получить объект, на котором стоит персонаж?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выбирай, что необходимо по задаче:

**[OnControllerColliderHit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/CharacterController.OnControllerColliderHit.html)** (связан с Character Controller) - вызывается тогда, когда контроллер сталкивается с коллайдеров, во время выполнения метода `Move`

```
void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit) {
     if (hit.normal.y > 0.9f)  // 0.9 можно изменить на другое значение
         varobjectStanding = hit.collider.gameObject;
 }
```

**[OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)** -  вызывается, когда этот `collider/rigidbody` начал соприкосновение с другим `rigidbody/collider`.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {        
    // collision - содержит инфу https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Collision.html
    Debug.Log(collision.gameObject.name);        
}
```

**[OnCollisionStay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionStay.html)** - вызывается один раз в кадр для каждого `collider/rigidbody`, который касается другого `rigidbody/collider`.

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collisionInfo) {
     // collisionInfo - содержит инфу https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Collision.html
    Debug.Log(collisionInfo.gameObject.name);      
}
```

**[Physics.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)** :

```
RaycastHit hit; // будет содержать инфу https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html
Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, distanceToGround + 0.1f);
 Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject);
```

еще есть **[OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html)** и **[OnTriggerStay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html)**